# Help with a Real Analysis proof related to subsequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

The exercise asks me to show that lim$(c^{\frac{1}{n}}) = 1 ,where, 0<c<1$, using subsequences.

Please verify my proof and help with the last part.

Here:

$$\frac{1}{n+1} < \frac{1}{n}
\Rightarrow c^{\frac{1}{n+1}} < c^{\frac{1}{n}} 
$$
Hence, it is a monotone decreasing sequence.

Since, $ 0<c<1$, we find, $0<c^{\frac{1}{n}}<1 $
Therefore, the sequence is bounded.

By the Monotone Convergence Theorem, the sequence is convergent.

Let $lim (c^{\frac{1}{n}}) = x $

Choosing $n*=2n$
We get a subsequence, $c^{\frac{1}{n*}} = c^{\frac{1}{2n}} = (c^{\frac{1}{n}})^{\frac{1}{2}} $

As limit of a sequence is equal to the limit of its subsequence, 
$$
x = lim (c^{\frac{1}{2n}})
= (\lim\limits (c^{\frac{1}{n}}))^{\frac{1}{2}}
= x^{\frac{1}{2}} 
$$
$$
\Rightarrow x^{2} - x = 0
\Rightarrow  x = 0, 1
$$
At this point in the proof, i am not sure how to proceed to show that x cannot be = 0. Or if there is something wrong with my proof, which is why i have reached such a result. 
Thank you!

Comment: Note that in your statement of $c^{\frac{1}{n+1}} < c^{\frac{1}{n}}$, if $c = \frac{1}{4}$ and $n = 1$, you're stating that $\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{1/2} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}} = \frac{1}{2}$ is less than $\frac{1}{4}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(c^{1/n})$ is actually increasing, not decreasing. [For $0<c<1$  $x<y$ imples $c^{x} >c^{y}$], Hence the limit cannot be $0$.